# Use build number in build task

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to use the build number as a version-suffix for a nuget package.

So I would like to have something like

```
dotnet pack --version-suffix=$(BuildNumber)
```

How can I access the build number variable?

Comment: What's the result if you use $(Build.BuildNumber)?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT that results in success \o/

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "arguments" field in the dotnet CLI task, you can pass additional arguments to the dotnet cli.

Using `--version-suffix $(Build.BuildNumber)` will pass the build number as version suffix. Make sure you don't have a `<version>` element set in your csproj, but rather a `<versionprefix>` element. The built version will look like `versionprefix-versionsuffix`, so for example, if you have `<versionprefix>1.2.3</versionprefix>` and build number `201703001`, the built version will be `1.2.3-201703001`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option of **Automatic package versioning** in NuGet Packager task.

- If your **Build number format** is like `{some_characters}_0.0.0.0`, so you can select `Use the build number` for **Automatic package versioning**.

[image]

- Else you can select `Use an environment variable` for **Automatic package versioning**, use your defined variable such as `temp` (`$(build.buildNumber)`) as **Environment variable**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This build task unfortunately fails to build my project (looks like it's calling the wrong msbuild version), so I can't check if this works, but I have the suspecion that this will try to set the version, not the version suffix.